# Dart PetitParser to get at AST datastructure created with ExpressionBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, petitparser

I'm new to petitparser, but it looks like it's the sonic screwdriver of parsers.

For my first project, I'm building code to parse a simple expression that builds an AST tree of my Node objects, then walks that tree with a few rules to minimize the unneeded parens.  I don't know what to pass to the output of .parse() (seems to be a Result) to get access to the tree I defined, so I can call .visit() on the top of the AST.  Any ideas?

```
class RIPParser {
  Parser _make_parser() {
    final builder = ExpressionBuilder();

    // precedence 5
    builder.group()
      ..primitive(digit()
          .plus()
          .seq(char('.').seq(digit().plus()).optional())
          .flatten()
          .trim()
          .map((a) => Node(precedence: 5, value: a)))
      ..wrapper(char('(').trim(), char(')').trim(),
          (l, a, r) => Node(precedence: 5, left: l, value: a, right: r));
    // negation is a prefix operator
    // precedence 4
    builder.group()
      ..prefix(
          char('-').trim(), (op, a) => Node(precedence: 4, value: '$op$a'));

    // power is right-associative
    // precedence 3
    builder.group()
      ..right(char('^').trim(),
          (a, op, b) => Node(precedence: 3, left: a, value: op, right: b));

    // multiplication and addition are left-associative
    // precedence 2
    builder.group()
      ..left(char('*').trim(),
          (a, op, b) => Node(precedence: 2, left: a, value: op, right: b))
      ..left(char('/').trim(),
          (a, op, b) => Node(precedence: 2, left: a, value: op, right: b));
    // precedence 1
    builder.group()
      ..left(char('+').trim(),
          (a, op, b) => Node(precedence: 1, left: a, value: op, right: b))
      ..left(char('-').trim(),
          (a, op, b) => Node(precedence: 1, value: op, left: a, right: b));

    final parser = builder.build().end();

    return parser;
  }

  Result parse(String input) {
    var parser = _make_parser();
    var result = parser.parse(input);
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short call `result.value` to get your parse-tree, or to throw a `ParserException` in case of an error.

For more details have a look at the class documentation of [Result](https://pub.dev/documentation/petitparser/latest/petitparser.context/Result-class.html), which is either a [Success](https://pub.dev/documentation/petitparser/latest/petitparser.context/Success-class.html) or a [Failure](https://pub.dev/documentation/petitparser/latest/petitparser.context/Failure-class.html) instance. In both cases the objects contain extra information, such as how much input was consumed or in case of an error what went wrong.

Update: I've tried to clarify the documentation on the mentioned classes in [8698f91](https://github.com/petitparser/dart-petitparser/commit/8698f917aa79022a4bfc88eee3a7593b0f065cfd).